# Equivalent function to shapely's envelope in ogr?

Tags: python, ogr, shapely, extents

I wrote a very simple python function that gives me the envelope/bounding box/...based on two coordinate pairs (ower left and upper right corner):

```
# ...
def get_bounding_box(self, ll_corner, ur_corner):
    try:
        from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
        mp_env = MultiPoint([ll_corner, ur_corner]).envelope
        return ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt( mp_env.to_wkt() )

print mp_env
POLYGON ((4.8439699999999997 52.3661099999999990, 4.8469199999999999 52.3661099999999990, 4.8469199999999999 52.3706000000000031, 4.8439699999999997 52.3706000000000031, 4.8439699999999997 52.3661099999999990))
```

As you can see I'm returning an ogr geometry which I use, for instance, in this manner:

```
bbox = geo.get_bounding_box(lowerleft,upper_right) 
...
p=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
p.AddPoint(x,y)
if p.Within(bbox):
    ....
```

Isn't there an equivalent function to shapely's envelope in ogr? Both `.ConvexHull()` and `GetEnvelope()` return only the two corner coordinate pairs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Ogr function  GetEnvelope() returns "a tuple (minX, maxX, minY, maxY)" ([from here](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#calculate-envelope-of-a-geometry)), but what you want (from what I can understand) is a Polygon describing the envelope/bbox?

This is actually rather simple, as the tuple (minX, maxX, minY, maxY) is all you need to create a Polygon.

Just create a Polygon based these, like so:

```
from osgeo import ogr

def my_envelope(geom):
   (minX, maxX, minY, maxY) = geom.GetEnvelope()

    # Create ring
    ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
    ring.AddPoint(minX, minY)
    ring.AddPoint(maxX, minY)
    ring.AddPoint(maxX, maxY)
    ring.AddPoint(minX, maxY)
    ring.AddPoint(minX, minY)

    # Create polygon
    poly_envelope = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
    poly_envelope.AddGeometry(ring)
    return poly_envelope
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So to makes things clear: there is no ogr build-in function that does this?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Hi @atlefren, thanks for the code, I've tried to create polygon shapefiles out of this based on my polygon shapefiles. but I can't seem to get it work. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Matt "can't seem to get it to work" is a far too vague "question". What does not work? My suggested function? How does it not work?

Comment: @atlefren as I said I'm trying to create polygon shapfiles out of my_envelope function you provided above. But it only creates an empty shapefile. Here's the link to the question I've raised. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274687/creating-polygon-shapefile-from-bounding-box-in-ogr-from-osgeo

Comment: @Matt there are several steps between using my function and creating a shapefile, so that's why I'm asking. Might be something wrong as well, but the idea should be fine.

Comment: Just leaving this here: GetEnvelope is not the Minimum Bouding Rectangle.