# Calculate geographic size in meters given lower left coordinate and upper right coordinate

Tags: scale

How do you find the geographic size in meters given a lower left coordinate and upper right coordinate. The projection would be WGS84 projection. Ex. 33,-119,35,-117. What would be the area in meters that covers?

Comment: The answer depends on the units -- I assume you are giving latitude/longitude in degrees here?

Comment: Yes WGS84 is correct.

Comment: The answer will also depend on what Projected Coordinate System you choose to project into. Would you be able to edit your question to specify that, please?

Answer (score 1):

So, with ArcMap, from [ESRI Forums](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1741&t=128032):

```
Private Function PolygonFromEnvelope(pEnv As IEnvelope) As IPolygon

Dim pPtColl As IPointCollection

Set pPtColl = New Polygon
With pPtColl
    .AddPoint pEnv.LowerLeft
    .AddPoint pEnv.UpperLeft
    .AddPoint pEnv.UpperRight
    .AddPoint pEnv.LowerRight
    'Close the polygon
    .AddPoint pEnv.LowerLeft
End With
Set PolygonFromEnvelope = pPtColl

End Function
```

then [Measure Area (ArcMAP 10.2)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000022000000)

or maybe [using GDAL/OGR](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90205/equivalent-function-to-shapelys-envelope-in-ogr):

```
from osgeo import ogr

    def my_envelope(geom):
       (minX, maxX, minY, maxY) = geom.GetEnvelope()

        # Create ring
        ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
        ring.AddPoint(minX, minY)
        ring.AddPoint(maxX, minY)
        ring.AddPoint(maxX, maxY)
        ring.AddPoint(minX, maxY)
        ring.AddPoint(minX, minY)

        # Create polygon
        poly_envelope = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
        poly_envelope.AddGeometry(ring)
        return poly_envelope
```

then [calculate the polygon area (QGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-in-qgis) or [OGR get_area()](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#calculate-the-area-of-a-geometry) although I'm not well-versed on GDAL/OGR so I'm not sure how it takes into account the coordinate system. QGIS should calculate with the projection in mind.