# Creating polygon shapefile from bounding box in ogr from osgeo?

Tags: python, ogr

I'm trying to create a polygon shapefile from a bounding box in ogr but it creates an empty shapefile. Here's the code:

```
from osgeo import ogr

infc = r"C:\Temp\infc.shp"
layer_name = 'outfc_bbx'

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
vector = driver.Open(infc)
in_lyr = vector.GetLayer()

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile') # will select the driver foir our shp-file creation.
shapeData = driver.CreateDataSource(r"C:\Temp") #so there we will store our data
out_lyr = shapeData.CreateLayer(layer_name, in_lyr.GetSpatialRef(), ogr.wkbPolygon) #this will create a corresponding layer for our data with given spatial information.
out_lyr.CreateFields(in_lyr.schema)
out_defn = out_lyr.GetLayerDefn()
out_feat = ogr.Feature(out_defn)

feature = in_lyr.GetFeature(0)
geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
geom.GetEnvelope()
(minX, maxX, minY, maxY) = geom.GetEnvelope()
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(minX, minY)
ring.AddPoint(maxX, minY)
ring.AddPoint(maxX, maxY)
ring.AddPoint(minX, maxY)
ring.AddPoint(minX, minY)
polygon_env = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
#poly = polygon_env.GetGeometryRef(0)
out_feat.SetGeometry(polygon_env)
out_lyr.CreateFeature(out_feat)
```

Comment: Think you have to call Destroy() on the layer and data source

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new feature:

```
feature = in_lyr.GetFeature(0)
geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
geom.GetEnvelope()
(minX, maxX, minY, maxY) = geom.GetEnvelope()
```

Then you create the ring for the polygon:

```
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(minX, minY)
ring.AddPoint(maxX, minY)
ring.AddPoint(maxX, maxY)
ring.AddPoint(minX, maxY)
ring.AddPoint(minX, minY)
```

Now you create your polygon for the bounding box:

```
polygon_env = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
#poly = polygon_env.GetGeometryRef(0)
```

And here you add the bounding box polygon to the layer:

```
out_feat.SetGeometry(polygon_env)
out_lyr.CreateFeature(out_feat)
```

But you haven't actually connected the ring to the bounding box polygon. The bounding box polygon is empty, because you still need to add the ring to the polygon:

```
...
polygon_env = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)

# This is the missing line:
polygon_env.AddGeometry(ring)

# Add the polygon to the new feature.
out_feat.SetGeometry(polygon_env)
...
```

Comment: Hi @Chau, thanks for your reply. But I still get an empty polygon shapefile.

Comment: @Matt, then I think we need some test data to try out (maybe just the WKT of the first feature in your data). When I run your code with my own linestring input data, I get a shape file with one bbox. Are you sure that the first geometry isn't an empty geometry or null geometry?

Comment: doesn't work. I checked the features, all are good. I've tried polyline shapefiles as input as well as polygons shapefiles as input.

Comment: @Matt can you give me some data to test on?